# How can I open the Facebook App for sharing a link on WP8?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wonder how to open the official Facebook App for sharing an URI from my C# code on Windows Phone. The common Uri-Scheme like `"fb://"` may open the App but no parameter seems to work. I have something like this in mind, but it will not work for me:

```
LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo"));
```

Of course I know that I could use the `ShareTask` but that's not what I want.
You can take a look at the Spotfy App, it does exactly, what I want to do, when sharing a song.

Thank you for your help and answers!

PS: Same with Twitter by the way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved it!
It took me nearly two days to find the solution and it is not documented anywhere sothat I would like to share my results with you:

```
// Open official Facebook app for sharing
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post?text=foo"));
```

I think this is a very cool feature and reminds users of how it works on other plarforms.

In conclusion launching other apps from your app via URI schemes is always a great scenario with a nice user experience.

**Hint**: *Opening the official Facebook App via URI schemes requires at least version 4.1!*

Comment: This looks really cool. Have you figured out if other apps like Twitter an Foursquare etc also have custom URI schemes?

Comment: Twitter and Spotify for example do have those schemes. Unfortunately they are nearly completely undocumented which makes it really hard to implement them.

Comment: Thanks for this, Please also share twitter if you ever find it!

Comment: Hi, This is good solution to open facebook app. In my case i need to check weather facebook app is installed or not. In this solution If fb not installed i'm getting popup message. Is there any to check condition installed or not??

Comment: hi! Do you have a link where I can find all the parameters for this link. I'd like to share a link from my app. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

If you wanna share the link, you can use `ShareLinkTask`

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
shareLinkTask.Title = "My Title";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://fb.me/profile.php", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Yep. I can share a link on facebook.";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

When user calls this method, it will show the sharable social networking apps installed on the phone, so you can share a link on the facebook, twitter & etc (if installed)

If you wanna share the local media file, you can use `ShareMediaTask`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned using the `ShareTask` or `ShareLinkTask` is not what I want to do. I wish to open the official Facebook App by using `LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo"));` and post the status there. So it is done on all other platforms and WP8 is able to perform that, too. Spotify App does this...