# How to share a windows phone app via facebook?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app and I want to have a button called share, to share this app on facebook. After I press/tap that button I want the link "www.blabla.com" to appear on my facebook profile if I'm logged, and if not, to appear a dialog of logging which will not be made by me (it must be a package to do this). I'm not really sure if this is possible but it's not me who requests this. I've tried some other web pages (including this: [How to share something using the Twitter app on Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753095/how-to-share-something-using-the-twitter-app-on-windows-phone-8)) but I am having a hard time getting solution at this point.

Is it possible to do something like this? Otherwise, any close alternative?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the `ShareLinkTask`to share the link over `Facebook`.

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri( "www.blabla.com", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Sample Facebook message!";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

A best reference would be this:

[Sharing from Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/)

or even you can refer the one from msdn: [How to use the share link task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394009(v=vs.105).aspx)

Hope it helps!