# Windows Phone 8 fb:post status?

Tags: facebook, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I've been searching the WP8 URI schemes in order to launch the fb app from a Silverlight WP8 app but I only have seen this answer:

[How can I open the Facebook App for sharing a link on WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351400/how-can-i-open-the-facebook-app-for-sharing-a-link-on-wp8)

sample:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post?text=foo"));
```

People says there is a fb:post definition in

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_Association_Schemes_List

But it appears that the references have been deleted.

Does anyone know if this functionality is being deprecated by facebook with their latest API changes or something like this? I would like to share content with this functionality but I only can send text as param and I must add an image :S

Thanks for all and sorry for my english ;)